# Kudu Debug console Bash vs SSH

Tags: azure, kudu

There is a menu on top of Kudu in the Azure Portal when using a App Service on Linux: Debug console.
The "Debug console" menu has two choices: Bash and SSH.

What is the difference between them?
It looks like they follow to different environments.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **Bash** feature launches a shell inside the *Kudu* instance. This is not the same as the container running your app. From the kudu instance, you have access to view log files and other info - and even delete log files - but you cannot access environment variables or see your deployed application code (other than a gzip archive of the content of the latest deployment at `/home/site/wwwroot/output.tar.gz`).

The **SSH** feature - "SSH" in the old kudu UI at `https://YOURAPPSVCNAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/` or "WebSSH" in the new UI at `https://YOURAPPSVCNAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui` - opens up an ssh connection to *one of the running instances of your application*. From here, you can see env vars, examine your code in its deployed directory structure, explore the file system as the app sees it, etc.

**NOTE**: if your app is running across multiple instances (configurable in your App Service Plan), the old Kudu UI doesn't let you easily select a specific instance. The new Kudu UI does: at the **Home** screen, the top box shows what instance you are attached to and presents a **Switch Instance** dropdown listing other ones.