# Azure Web App Linux: Node version always wrong

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Created an Azure Linux Web App with Node 18 Stack.

`node --version` returns 14.19.2

Since hours, I am trying to set the runtime version to 18. What I tried:

1. Setting `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `18.x` or a concrete version, e.g. `18.19.1`, restarted. Azure does not care.
2. Setting the stack manually to Node 18 explicitly under Configuration / General Settings / Stack Settings. Restarted. Azure does not care.
3. Checked the setting in the cloud shell using

`az webapp config show --name axiocontentstrapi --resource-group axio-headless1 | jq '.linuxFxVersion'`

Of course, it say NODE 18 while the real `node --version` is still 14.19.2
Then I tried to reconfigure using

`az webapp config set --resource-group axio-headless --name axiocontentstrapi --linux-fx-version "NODE|18-lts"`
Azure still doesn't care.

4. Checked the DevOps Pipeline setting of my "Deploy to Azure App Service" job. It is set to Node 18.

I need a higher Node version for my App to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It looks like you are trying to check the NodeJS version from the Bash section of Azure Web app which will show Node 14 by default*. I have raised a [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/appservice-linux/issues/8) to get more insights into this issue.

***When I checked the NodeJs version via SSH console it correctly gave Node 18.19.0 version. Refer below:-***

**My Azure Linux Web App:-**

[image]

***Azure CLI commands:-***

```bash
az webapp config show --resource-group siliconrg6543 --name valleywebapp98 --query linuxFxVersion
az webapp list-runtimes --os linux | grep NODE
```

[image]

***When I `SSH into Kudu console` by existing and new ui I receive `Node 18` version:-***

```bash
node --version
```

[image]

**New ui:-**

```http
https://valleywebapp98.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/webssh
```

[image]

***When I checked Node version in Bash it showed Node 14 version:-***

***Azure Web app kudu > Bash output:-***

[image]

**New ui:-**

```http
https://valleywebapp98.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/kududebug
```

[image]

I have also tried setting the NodeJs Runtime in Azure Devops pipeline still the same issue when accessing the node version from Bash:-

```yaml
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: valleywebApp98'
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription (0xxxxxxxxx)'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
              WebAppName: '$(webAppName)'
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              RuntimeStack: 'NODE|18-lts'
              StartupCommand: 'npm run start'
              ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
              InlineScript: |
                npm install
                npm run build --if-present
```

***References:-***

[Which versions of node.js are available on Azure Web Sites? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515421/which-versions-of-node-js-are-available-on-azure-web-sites)

[How to fix version mismatch between runtime node version and actual node version - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/answers/questions/1456607/how-to-fix-version-mismatch-between-runtime-node-v)

Comment: Ah, yes! I can reproduce that: Bash is showing me the old Node version (which was what i did check all the time) and WebSSH shows the expected Node version. I could move forward with that. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [App Service Linux documentation](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Runtime_Support/node_support.md#node-on-linux-app-service), your command should have worked.

Have you tried restarting your App Service Plan? You can do it via the [rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-plans/reboot-worker?view=rest-appservice-2023-01-01).

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue in Linux Web App. But it works for Windows Web App.

When run `node --version` in Kudu Bash, the version returned is 14.19.2.
[image]

When I run `node --version` in Kudu SSH, the version returned is 16.13.1.
[image]

To resolve this issue, you can manually change stack from Configuration -> General Settings -> Stack Settings.
[image]

Wait for a while and then run `node --version` from Kudu SSH `https://{webappname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host`. What it should return is 18.19.0.
[image]

To check the node version installed in the container running your app, you should check in SSH. See the differences between Bash and SSH from [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273884/kudu-debug-console-bash-vs-ssh).

If you set `runtimeStack` in DevOps pipeline task `AzureWebApp@1`, ensure to use `runtimeStack: 'NODE|18-lts'` instead of something like `runtimeStack: 'NODE|18.x'`.

```
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|18-lts'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'npm run start'
```